# Arranging Activities and Breaks Under a "Stamina" Constraint

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, schedule, greedy

I am trying to create an algorithm to solve a problem where (to simplify), you have to complete n different activities, and can only start activity i after time min_start[i], for i from 0 to (n-1). Each activity takes t minutes to complete, but you have a limitation that you can only complete s activities before taking a break (and a break takes b minutes). You can leave any amount of space in between periods of activity or break, but an explicitly stated "break period" of b minutes is required to reset the stamina counter s. The goal is to find a schedule of activity and break start times to finish all the activities as soon as possible.

Is there an O(n) algorithm to solve this problem? I tried a greedy algorithm but came up with the two following examples where greedy seemed to fail. I am thinking this might be solvable with dynamic programming, but I can't figure out how to make a table of size O(n) with O(1) time at each step (seems like you need an extra dimension).

Example 1:

- b=2, t=1, s=3, n=5, min_start=(0, 2, 3, 4, 6)
- Optimal solution: (act0@0, act1@2, act3@3, break@4, act4@6, act5@7)
- Optimal finish time = 8

Example 2:

- b=2, t=1, s=4, n=5, min_start=(0, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Optimal solution: (act0@0, break@1, act2@3, act3@4, act4@5, act5@6)
- Optimal finish time = 7

I believe one interesting strategy could be to start from the back of the list and choose the optimal place for a break among the last (s+1) lectures. Then you can "cut off" the break and all lectures after it and you have a smaller subproblem. I'm just not sure how this could be done in linear time, unless the optimal place for the last break among the last (s+1) lectures could be computed in constant time, or maybe there's some sort of amortized analysis that could lead to O(n) time in total without O(1) time at each of these steps.

Comment: Have you tried making a tree with memoization? That is often a useful precursor to trying to make a table. And do you need O(N), or just a fast solution?

Comment: I'll think about that, thanks. It has to be O(n) time.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tabulation-vs-memoization/